# how to remove spaces in between flexitems in flex box model

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to remove spaces between the flex-item in flex-box model. please check my pen

i want 6th element to be aligned right next to 2nd element
similarly 7th element next to 3rd and similarly 
8th element next to 4th

i dont want any space between those elements. by any chance can i acheive this using flex-box model ?

any help is appreciated.

thanks,

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  height:600px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.flex1{
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item flex1">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">2</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex4">4</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex5">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex6">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex1">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">8</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex3">9</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex4">10</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex5">11</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex6">12</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex1">13</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">14</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex3">15</li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that. I think you're actually looking for a floating behaviour

Comment: I assume same. Im trying to build windows 8 home page. which has fixed height for each group [see that in this fiddle but it works on IE11 only] (http://jsfiddle.net/heLptzcr/14/). in this child elements have fixed width if i change the width the layout is not fluid. I think we cant achieve desired layout using floated elements

Comment: Basically a container of fluid widgets? I think I would go about it like this:
1. Define a grid system (e.g. 10x10 pixels)
2. Calculate minimum size of each widget/element and round up to fit with grid units
3. Write a good-enough algorithm to stack elements

But it's really not the way the web works.

Comment: @ThomasJensen: Okay. Thanks

Comment: Wait a minute @user4709780, I like this challenge. Give me 24 hours because I got some work to do.  Btw, if you want more members to take your question seriously, I suggest you change your name from "user4709780" to something that shows you put some thought into it.

Comment: So is your objective is to have 2 columns..what goes next to item 1... item 15?

Comment: @zer00ne: Hey, Thanks for trying it. My objective is to make a windows 8 home screen. if you have IE11 installed please try this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdKYaL). that pen is working only on IE 11.

Comment: wht i was trying to do is. I was trying to build a windows 8 tile based home screen. but it should expand dynamically for each group in the above pen you can able to see some groups if i add an item to each group, that particular group has to expand.

Comment: @zer00ne I dont know why that pen isnt working in chrome/ firefox. its working perfectly in IE. that is one more strange issue i found.

Comment: @Mustang Maniac Ok, it's not exactly what you asked for, but close enough for a good start in the right direction. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's got a button you click on and it will reorder the flex items randomly. It's not perfect, It doesn't always end up with 3 blocks for the bottom row.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/01/pen/BNbpLN)

### HTML

```
<header>
  <fieldset id="ui">
    <legend><span class="dropcap">F</span><span>lexbox</span> <span class="big">R</span><span>andom</span> <span class="big">O</span><span>rdered</span> <span class="big">G</span><span>rid</span></legend>
    <button id="btn">
      <a href='#'>Shuffle</a>
    </button>
  </fieldset>
</header>
<main id="flexMain" class="flexible">
  <ul id="flexShell">
    <li class="flexItem">01</li>
    <li class="flexItem">02</li>
    <li class="flexItem">03</li>
    <li class="flexItem">04</li>
    <li class="flexItem">05</li>
    <li class="flexItem">06</li>
    <li class="flexItem">07</li>
    <li class="flexItem">08</li>
    <li class="flexItem">09</li>
    <li class="flexItem">01</li>
    <li class="flexItem">11</li>
    <li class="flexItem">12</li>
    <li class="flexItem">13</li>
    <li class="flexItem">14</li>
    <li class="flexItem">15</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

### CSS

```
html {
  color: #000;
  font: 600 16px/1.45 Consolas;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  color: #003F7D;
}

#flexMain {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  jusify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#flexShell {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: -2px;
}

.flexItem {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 5em;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.flexible * {
  text-align: center;
  outline: 3px solid hsla(60, 20%, 50%, .7);
}

li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  width: 10em;
  background: hsla(0, 100%, 70%, 1);
  max-width: 60em;
}

li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  width: 10em;
  background: #33FF66;
  max-width: 40em;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  width: 20em;
  background: hsla(195, 100%, 60%, 1);
  max-width: 80em;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: transparent;
}

#ui {
  position: relative;
  top: 48px;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #F33;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: table;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #fc3;
  height: 28px;
  width: 64px;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .7);
  border: 1px solid #FC3;
  display: table-cell;
}

legend {
  color: #6A2244;
  font: 600 1.5rem/1.2 "Book Antiqua";
  font-variant: small-caps;
  float: left;
}

.dropcap {
  color: #FD9;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  font-size: 3.26em;
  line-height: .5em;
  margin: .205em .1em 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropcap + span {
  -1em;
}

.big {
  color: #FD9;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

### JS

```
function qa(sel, ele) {
  if (!ele) {
    ele = document;
  }
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(ele.querySelectorAll(sel));
}
var fxArr = qa('.flexItem');
var rand = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var frq = rand(1, 15);

function shuffle(frq, arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < frq; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
      var n = rand(1, 15);
      var fx = arr[k];
      fx.style.order = n;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  shuffle(frq, fxArr);
}, true);

window.onload = shuffle(frq, fxArr);
```

Comment: appreciate your effort.Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing your pen for you, but was fruitless.

Personally I think, unfortunately like with many projects you will need to put more work into it than it may first appear is needed.

I'd suggest just using responsive css, you can even use something like bootstrap to hurry up the process, although I don't think doing it by hand should be very difficult.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for trying. But it is not my work related project. I just want to build that for fun. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Good on you Mustang. If you find a solution, let us know :)